# How to persist an object that is passed by reference in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ramda.js

I'm working on this task where I need to do the following:
I have this object passed by reference from 4 components

```js
const initialStateSubjects = {
"1":{
"name": "math",
"selected": true}
"2":{
"name": "English",
"selected": true} 
}

const Subjects = {
"1":{
"name": "math",
"selected": false}
"2":{
"name": "English",
"selected": true} 
}

const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState(initialStateSubjects)
const [changedState, setChangedState] = useState(initialStateSubjects)

//this is the way I'm filtering but it's not working because it's comparing two identical objects

const changedSubjects = Object.keys(changedState)
.filter(key => initialState[key]?.selected !== changedState[key]?.selected
.map(key => console.log(initialState[key]?.name))
```

As you can see they both need to have the same object passed which is `initialStateSubjects`
Most of the logic is done with the changedState, and I only set the initial one once in the useEffect, but regardless, both the `initialState` & `changedState` gets changed at the same time. I want to use the initial value of Initial state to compare the difference and return the name of the subjects that `selected` values changed. I have tried doing in this in the console and it works brilliantly but when doing in React I am stuck with this. I have tried spread operator to make a shallow copy of it, and used a library to make a deep clone of it but it still mutates the initial object. If you do think of a different way to compare initial state without creating another state that would also work for me because all I want is to return the ones that changed upon clicking a button from their original initial state. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the complete code? I do not understand how are you updating your state. Also, why are we using  `subjectsObj` for the initial state? Shouldn't the initial state be `InitialStateSubjects`?

Comment: @AkshayMathur Thanks for spotting out the typo. It's for work and can't share the complete code. I am updating the state in useEffect and onToggle method. All I want is for the initial state not to change at all unless page is refreshed or the toggle dropdown method is fired by a click event. The problem is both are using the same object by reference so they both get update at the same time, and I can't persist the initial state of the object.

Comment: I think you really need to supply more code.  If the original code is out-of-bounds, simply create a [mcve] that has the same behavior.  For now I can't tell what the current behavior is or what behavior you actually want.  One very random guess would be that maybe it would be better if you passed separate copies of `R.clone(initialStateSubjects)` to each `useState`, but it's possible that this is exactly backward from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what the exact requirement is since you cannot provide the entire code. But here is a working implementation for a simple dropdown that might help you. If you require a copy of the initial state only for comparison, then in that case you do not actually need to maintain 2 copies. A single state implementation can be used here.

```
import React from "react";

const initialStateSubjects = {
  "1": {
    name: "Math",
    selected: false
  },
  "2": {
    name: "English",
    selected: false
  }
};
export default function App() {
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState(initialStateSubjects);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInitialState((prevState) => {
      return Object.values(prevState).map((val) => {
        val.name === e.target.value
          ? (val.selected = true)
          : (val.selected = false);
        return val;
      });
    });
    console.log(initialState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {Object.keys(initialState).map((sub) => (
          <option key={sub}>{initialState[sub].name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```